# Check if two websites are same

Tags: web, redirect

I am having two websites as below,

website1 - `f1.com`
website2 - `formula1.com`

I need to check if either of the two website is redirecting to other website. For example, in above case, `f1.com` is redirecting to `formula1.com`.

Currently I am checking it by launching both websites in chrome using Uipath tool and checking if either of the websites is redirecting to other website using “Get Attribute” activity. However I am having thousands of such pairs of websites and above approach is taking lot of time.

Can anyone please advise if there is a better way of checking it? We can use any other applicable attribute for this check also (example - IP address).

Comment: rather than opening chrome and all the associated overhead, you could make a web request to each programatically and see if the response is a redirect status (301/302) -- this might not catch all if they redirect you in some other way, but most will do it sensibly

Comment: I checked f1.com in postman and it is giving Response Code 200 even if it is redirecting to formula1.com.

Comment: On the request in Postman, look at the 'Settings' tab -- there's an "Automatically follow redirects" which is set to On by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can check using https://curl.se/ on the command line. Curl is available for all platforms including Mac, Windows, and Linux.  Here I'm using it in conjunction with `grep` on Linux to filter the results to just the the interesting lines:

```
$ curl -s --head https://f1.com/ | grep -Ei '^(HTTP|location)'
HTTP/2 301 
location: https://www.formula1.com/
```